# How do I free the memory used from node_load()?

Tags: 7, nodes, performance

I am using code similar to the following one.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
   $nid = get_node_id($i);
   $node = node_load($nid);
   $data = [
     $node->field_1,
     $node->field_3,
     ...
   ];
   save_to_database($data);

   echo round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2) . ' MB'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Every time a loop is completed, the used memory is increased. For example, after the first loop, the used memory is 110 MB, and after the third loop is 230 MB.

How do I avoid the used memory keep increasing?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What you describe is a task for Dupal's Batch API. Implementing it you'd pass the node one after the other to a dedicated process to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: @leymannx You should add that as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `node_load()`, as every Drupal function that loads entities from the database, stores in memory the loaded entity. If you want to avoid that happens, you can use code similar to the following one.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  $nid = get_node_id($i);
  $node = entity_load('node', array($nid), array(), TRUE);
  $data = [
    $node->field_1,
    $node->field_3,
  ];
  save_to_database($data);
}
```

The last argument of [`entity_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7.x) is telling Drupal not to store in memory cache the previously loaded entity.

This is what happens with the default entity controller implemented from Drupal, [`DrupalDefaultEntityController`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/DrupalDefaultEntityController/7.x), which uses the following code for [`DrupalDefaultEntityController::resetCache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/function/DrupalDefaultEntityController%3A%3AresetCache/7.x).

```
public function resetCache(array $ids = NULL) {
  if (isset($ids)) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
      unset($this->entityCache[$id]);
    }
  }
  else {
    $this->entityCache = array();
  }
}
```